# Spring jdbcTemplate passing constant value to an query method

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, jdbctemplate

Is it possible to mention an values as constant in the function.  I have an entity say, EntityClass. Then a repository interface over it, say

```
interface EntityClassRepository extends CrudRepository<EntityClass, String> {

List<EntityClass> findById(String id);
}
```

Can I hard code some value in the method like,

```
List<EntityClass> findByIdAndActiveFlagAsY(String id);
```

To only query the ones where active flag column's value is `'Y'`.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, spring data not support **AS** keywords inside method names, you can check all the [Supported keywords inside method names](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.5.0.RC1/reference/html/repository-query-keywords.html) :

[image: Supported keywords CrudeRepository]

---

So to solve your problem you can use custom query instead :

```
@Query("from EntityClass e WHERE id = :id AND ActiveFlag = 'Y'")
public List<EntityClass> findByIdAndActiveFlagAsY(@Param("id") String id);
```

Or you can use `Equals` keywords but you should to send the value in the method :

```
@Query("from EntityClass e WHERE id = :id AND ActiveFlag = :flag")
public List<EntityClass> findByIdAndActiveFlagEquals(@Param("id") String id, @Param("flag") String flag);
```